# Moving between rooms in python text based game

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whenever I type my input for going South or any direction, I stay in the same room. The point of the game is to move from room to room and get an item.

```
rooms = {
    'Front Lobby': {'West': 'Ice Rink'},
    'Ice Rink': {'North': 'Away Locker Room', 'East': 'Front Lobby', 'West': 'Mens Locker Room', 'South': 'Lounge'},
    'Away Locker Room': {'East': 'Pro Shop', 'South': 'Ice Rink'},
    'Pro Shop': {'West': 'Away Locker Room'},
    'Mens Locker Room': {'West': 'Ice Rink'},
    'Lounge': {'West': 'Womens Locker Room', 'East': 'Skate Rentals', 'North': 'Ice Rink'},
    'Womens Locker Room': {'East': 'Lounge'},
    'Skate Rentals': {'West': 'Lounge'}
}
gameOn = True
inventory = ['place holder']

# moves player from room to room
def move(player, direction):

    current_room = player

    # check if there is a room in the specified direction
    if direction in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]

    # error handling
    else:
        print("There is nothing in that direction!")

    # return the player state
        return current_room

# displays rules at start of game 
def showRules():

    print("- Collect 6 items to win the game, or have to get clowned by the other goalie.\n" "Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West.\n" "Add to Inventory: get 'item name'. Once all items collected type: ‘Finish’")


def main():
    showRules()
    player = ("Front Lobby", [])

    while gameOn:

        current_room = player

        # output
        print(f"\nYou are in the {current_room}")

        # Goalie got you
        if player[0] == 'Pro Shop':
                print('You make more excuses than saves. GAME OVER')
                break

        # input validation and parsing
        print("----------------")
        move = input("Enter your move:\n")

        # invalid move syntax
        if 'go ' in move or 'Finish' in move:
            continue
        else:
            print('Invalid Command')
            continue

        # split string 
        action = move.split()

        # move 
        if action[0] == 'go ':
            move(player, arg)
        elif action == 'Finish':
            print('Awesome! Now get on the ice! You Win.')

        # invalid action
        else:
            print("Invalid command!")

main()
```

Comment: `action = move.split()`, `if action[0] == 'go '`... try `== 'go'` without the space. `split()` will remove the spaces from either side of `go`.

Comment: Then you'll need to assign something to `arg` or replace `arg` with something…

Comment: `continue` does not do what you seem to think it does. It starts the current loop body from the beginning again. You probably meant `pass`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the

```
return current_room
```

is one indentation to far. This way it will only return when the else-statement is reached.

But also, maybe you should assign the value to current_room in the main function.

```
current_room = move(player, arg)
```

instead of this:

```
move(player, arg)
```

Then you should also change the move function so it returns the current room:

```
def move(player, direction):
    current_room = player
    # check if there is a room in the specified direction
    if direction in rooms[current_room]:
        return rooms[current_room][direction]
    # error handling
    else:
        print("There is nothing in that direction!")
```

This has to do with global and local variables. When changing the variable of a value within a function, that only changes within the function. Try this as a test (output a):

```
def move(x):
    x = 'b'

def main():
    x = 'a'
    move(x)
    print(x)

main()
```

And this (output b):

```
def move(x):
    x = 'b'
    return x

def main():
    x = 'a'
    x = move(x)
    print(x)

main()
```

Comment: and `action = move.split()`, `if action[0] == 'go '`, right

Comment: I think so Jack. Also as a tip, just try adding different print statements throughout your script. This way you see what parts of your script are reached and in what order, so you can see what is actually going on and find unexpected behavior early.

Comment: Im getting this error

File "main.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 75, in main
    move(player, action[1])
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @shawn you have a function called `move` but you "mask" it by making a string object called `move`. Rename one or the other and you'll be fine!

Answer (score 0):

So there were several errors, I marked them in the program:

```
rooms = {
    'Front Lobby': {'West': 'Ice Rink'},
    'Ice Rink': {'North': 'Away Locker Room', 'East': 'Front Lobby', 'West': 'Mens Locker Room', 'South': 'Lounge'},
    'Away Locker Room': {'East': 'Pro Shop', 'South': 'Ice Rink'},
    'Pro Shop': {'West': 'Away Locker Room'},
    'Mens Locker Room': {'West': 'Ice Rink'},
    'Lounge': {'West': 'Womens Locker Room', 'East': 'Skate Rentals', 'North': 'Ice Rink'},
    'Womens Locker Room': {'East': 'Lounge'},
    'Skate Rentals': {'West': 'Lounge'}
}
gameOn = True
inventory = ['place holder']

#moves player from room to room
def move(player, direction):
    global rooms
    current_room = player 

    # check if there is a room in the specified direction
    if direction in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]

    # error handling
    else:
        print("There is nothing in that direction!")
        return player # Returning the same room if nothing Exists in the direction

    # return the player state
    return current_room # Indent Error

#displays rules at start of game 
def showRules():

    print("- Collect 6 items to win the game, or have to get clowned by the other goalie.\n" "Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West.\n" "Add to Inventory: get 'item name'. Once all items collected type: ‘Finish’")


def main():
    showRules()
    player = "Front Lobby" # Acc. to me player should be a str not  tuple

    while gameOn:

        current_room = player

        # output
        print(f"\nYou are in the {current_room}")

        # Goalie got you
        if player == 'Pro Shop':
            print('You make more excuses than saves. GAME OVER')
            break

        # input validation and parsing
        print("----------------")
        player_move = input("Enter your move:\n") # because move is already a function

        # invalid move syntax
        if 'go' in player_move or 'Finish' in player_move:
                
    
            # split string 
            
            action = player_move.split(' ')
            print(action)        # move 
            if action[0] == 'go':
                player = move(player, action[1]) # Assigning the value to player 
                                                 # and giving a value since arg 
                                                 # isn't anything
            elif action == 'Finish':
                print('Awesome! Now get on the ice! You Win.')
    
            # invalid action
            else:
                print("Invalid command!")
        
        else:
            print('Invalid Command')
            continue


    

main()
```

Comment: Im not getting any errors now but I keep getting "You are in the front lobby" no matter what command

Comment: @shawnfrye turns out it works fine if you comment out the `#invalid move syntax` block, currently working on it. Update: Fixed, though I don't get the error fully myself, shifting the code into the `if 'go' in player_move or 'Finish' in player_move:` block fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Another problem:

```
if 'go ' in move or 'Finish' in move:
    continue
```

Continue will make the execution go to the top of the while loop, you can use pass here instead, or remove this if statement and change the else-statement to:

```
if direction not in rooms[current_room]:
    print("There is nothing in that direction!")
    return player # Returning the same room if nothing Exists in the direction
```